# Laravel 4 : Call to undefined method Redis::connection()

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, redis

I'm going crazy about this error.
I've got a vagrant VM with Debian 7, generated with Puphpet, installation was fine.

### 1. Redis is installed and working

`redis-server` is running :

[image: redis-server running]

I can use the server on `127.0.0.1:6379` :

[image]

### 2. php5-redis is installed

`php5-redis` is actually installed :

[image]

### 3. Laravel Redis config is set

Here is my redis config file in `app/local/database.php` :

```
'redis' => [

    'cluster' => false,

    'default' => [
    'host'     => '127.0.0.1',
    'port'     => 6379,
    'database' => 0,
    ],
],
```

### 4. The call to Redis is simple :

```
// Get redis
$redis = Redis::connection();
```

### 5. I tried a lot of things

```
sudo service nginx reload
sudo service redis-server force-reload
composer dumpautoload
```

But nothing solved the error.

---

I'm still having :

```
ERROR: exception 'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException' with message 'Call to undefined method Redis::connection()' in /var/www/fd/app/menus/admin.menu.php:16
```

(line 16 is where I do the connection `$redis = Redis::connection();`)

Where am I wrong ?

Btw, I hate mondays >.>

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I came across this after encountering this issue and wanted to add another answer in case it helps someone else.

In my case there was an alias collision because my php configuration has the PHP-Redis module/extension enabled -- both the PHP module and Laravel seem to have a conflicting object named Redis.  I was able to resolve this simply by using the entire namespaced identifier:

```php
//$r = Redis::connection() 
$r = Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis::connection();
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution. In fact, my vagrant machine had php-redis installed too, so in my case it was the correct answer ;)

Comment: Or maybe you can just add additional entry under app.php > aliases with the same value. Example: ``'Redis2'            => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis',`` Then do ``php artisan dump-autoload``

Comment: @lukaserat thanks you, this is what [Laravel's docs suggest](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/redis#introduction), but I didn't figure out exactly what they meant by:

`Note: If you have the Redis PHP extension installed via PECL, you will need to rename the alias for Redis in your app/config/app.php file.`

Apparently that means:

1. rename the alias in `app/config/app.php` from `'Redis' => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis',` to, i.e., `'LRedis' => ...`

2. issue `artisan dump-autoload` command

3. use that renamed alias in your code: `$r = LRedis::connection();`

Answer (score 6):

The problem isn't with your redis server setup -- there's something mis-configured or changed in your system.

The error you're seeing

```
Call to undefined method Redis::connection()
```

Is PHP telling you it can't find a method named `connection` on the class `Redis`.  It's a PHP error, and PHP never gets around to trying to talk to the redis server.

Normally, in a Laravel 4.2 system, there is no class named `Redis`.  Instead, an alias is setup in `app/config/app.php`

```
#File: app/config/app.php
'Redis'           => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis',
```

which turns `Redis` into a facade.  This is what enables you to make calls like `Redis::connection`.

So, there's something wrong with your system.  Either you

1. Have a custom class named `Redis` somewhere that's loaded before the aliases are setup
2. Have `Redis` aliased to something other than a the `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis` facade class
3. You `Redis` facade class has been modified to return a service identifier other than `redis`
4. You've rebound the `redis` service as some other class
5. Per the comments below, you have the `Redis` PHP extension installed and the global extension class "wins"

To find out where PHP thinks the `Redis` class is, try

```
$r = new ReflectionClass('Redis');
var_dump($r->getClassFile());
```

To see if `#4` is the problem, try calling the service directly

```
$app = app();
$app['redis']->connection();
```

Good luck!

Comment: Replacing all `Redis::connection()` with `$app['redis']->connection()` worked. I must have another error somewhere else, if I find it, I'll post it here in comments, thank you !

Comment: I ran into this problem recently with an installation of PHP 5.6 that happened to be running the php-redis module -- I came across this post as well as a Laravel github issue here:  https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/1066 .  In my case, and as it appears to happen on occasion, the Laravel Redis alias is colliding with the Redis PHP module.  Seems the best solution is to find the alias definition in Laravel and rename it to something like LRedis

Comment: +1 & tks for the reflection technique, which I'm sure will be extremely useful in a lot of scenarios and not just this.

Answer (score 2):

That error is because you have installed and enabled the module php5-redis, it became with the class Redis. To avoid that error and use the Laravel Redis Facade, you have to change the alias in app/config/app.php (or whatever is your environment).

`'Redis' => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis'`

`'RedisFacade' => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis' //whatever you like`

or just configure your cache.php to use Redis and use only the Cache class. :)

Answer (score 1):

Install Redis extension on your PC.

Download  the CORRECT version the DDL from the following link:
https://pecl.php.net/package/redis/4.1.0/windows

Put the dll in the correct folder

```
Wamp -> C:\wamp\bin\php\php-XXXX\ext
Laragon -> C:\laragon\bin\php\php-XXX\ext
```

Edit the `php.ini` file adding

```
extension=php_redis.dll
```

Restart server and check `phpinfo();`. Now Redis should be there!