# How to set up PhpRedis in Laravel 5+?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, redis, laravel-5.3, phpredis

**Background**
Attempting to use [PhpRedis](https://github.com/phpredis/phpredis) in Laravel 5.3 on a Mac OSX local server
running Apache 2.4.18, Php 7.0.14 and [homebrew](https://github.com/Homebrew)
...without requiring additional (non-official) composer libraries

[Redis](https://redis.io/) is installed via `homebrew install redis` and working
tested by `redis-cli ping` which gives `PONG`

[PhpRedis](https://github.com/phpredis/phpredis) installed via `homebrew install php70-redis` and working
tested by `php -r "if (new Redis() == true){ echo \"\r\n OK \r\n\"; }"` which gives `OK`

---

**Setup**
With the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/redis) and this [SO Laravel 4 solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26435931/3092596) I do the following:

1. change (or comment & add) `alias` definition in app/config/app.php  from
   `'Redis' => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis'`
   to
   `'LRedis' => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis'`
2. add client definition to the `redis` database definition in config/database.php
   `'client' => 'phpredis',`
3. run `composer dump-autoload` and `php artisan optimize`
4. use that renamed alias in an example route code:

   `Route::get('redistesturl', function () {
       $app = LRedis::connection();
       $app->set("name", "Bob Cool");
       print_r($app->get("name"));
   });`

---

**Errors**

```
FatalThrowableError in Database.php line 62:
Class 'Predis\Client' not found
```

Also tested calling redis within route as per [SO answer mentioned above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26435931/3092596) :

```
$redis = Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis::connection();
```

...but get same error

If I try to access `LRedis` class from within a controller like this:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis;

class MyController extends Controller
{
    public function redistest(){
        $redis = LRedis::connection();
        $redis->set('name', 'Bob Cool');
        return $redis->get('name');
    }
}
```

I get the following error:

```
FatalThrowableError in Preferences.php line 15:
Class 'App\Http\Controllers\LRedis' not found
```

---

**Notes**
Tested `Predis` and got it working fine by only adding the official `predis` library as specified in the docs.

I *can* get PhpRedis to work fine on my system (with the same route & controller examples) if I use an additional library [like this one](https://github.com/tillkruss/laravel-phpredis) by following [this Laracast](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/tutorial-guide-installing-php-redis-on-fresh-install-homestead-with-php7?page=0)  ...however this question is specifically:

"How to set up PhpRedis in Laravel 5+ *without* additional composer libraries?"

Comment: it wont work, because laravel by default use predis, which use redis & not phpredis, also this is why u r getting errors, so either install https://github.com/vetruvet/laravel-phpredis or https://github.com/tillkruss/laravel-phpredis

Answer (score 1):

```php
FatalThrowableError in Preferences.php line 15:
Class 'App\Http\Controllers\LRedis' not found
```

You have not include namespace for LRedis class

```php
<?php
use LRedis
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to PHP Redis binary.

https://github.com/phpredis/phpredis/blob/develop/INSTALL.markdown

```
pecl install redis
```